# Can I step over a whole loop in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

Suppose I'm debugging the following code in IntelliJ:

```
for (SomeObject obj1 : iterable1) {
   doSomething(obj1); // <--- I am currently paused on this line
   for (SomeObject obj2 : iterable2) {
      doSomething(obj1, obj2);
   }
}
```

I would like to step over the whole inner loop to see how the inner loop affected `obj1`'s fields, but "run to cursor" to the first closing brace runs only the first iteration of the inner loop, while "run to cursor" on the second closing brace ends the iteration of the outer loop, and I no longer have access to `obj1`.

Manually stepping through each of the iterations isn't an option since there may be thousands of items, and neither is adding a line between the braces since this is part of a library.

Is there any way I can simply step over a loop at the end of a block without exiting the containing block?

Comment: Make a breakpoint on the outer loop and use run button on the left side of the pane of the debugger section.

Comment: But then that instance of `obj1` is gone.

Comment: add a print statement after the inner loop body ends and then apply the breakpoint. Because you need something to pause your code, so any valid statement would do.

Comment: As I said in my question, this code is part of a library so I can't add any statements in it. Also, even if I could, having to restart the program every time I need to do this is not very convenient.

Comment: My bad didn't see that. I try something and get back to you.

Comment: How many items are in `iterable2`?  If you only a few items, then just go into the inner `doSomething()` method and add a breakpoint at the end.  Then, just F9 through a few times until you know you are on the last element.  Of course, this assumes that you only have a few items.

Comment: That's not an option, there are a few thousand items, and I don't have an index such that I can set a conditional breakpoint.

Comment: @Runemoro Add a conditional breakpoint at `doSomething(obj1, obj2);` and condition should be `obj2 == iterable2.get(iterable2.size() - 1)`. Then move one line ahead and you'll see the value of obj1

Comment: @AshvinSharma `obj2 == iterable2.size() - 1` doesn't compile... obj2 isn't an int. This is a set iterator so I also can't do `obj2 == iterable2.get(iterable2.size() - 1)`.

Comment: So there's no way you can check if the `obj2` is the last object in `iterable2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround:

1. While paused on the `doSomething(obj1);` line, I right-clicked the `obj1` variable in the "Variables" pane and chose "Mark Object", naming it "obj1Instance"
2. I let the loop run one iteration and ran `obj1Instance_DebugLabel` in the "Evaluate Expression" window, which showed me all of its fields

I also submitted an IntelliJ issue here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-194103

Answer (score 0):

I'd put a breakpoint on the `doSomething(obj1)` line, and then use "Resume Program' (i.e., <kbd>F9</kbd>) to return to it in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: This won't really work either, because the OP wants to see the state of `obj1` _after_ the `doSomething` method has completed.  See my comment above.